# Link error Visual C++ 2010 ImageMagick

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, imagemagick

So I used the VisualMagick tool to set up a Static Library project and compiled all of the ImageMagick Source to static lib files. Then I created a new solution and moved all those libs and the needed .h files to my lib folder in my new solution. My cpp file that I want to use the lib files compiles fine, even with `#include Magick++.h` in the header, until I add any references to things in imageMagick. Like if I say `Magick::Image image;` It will give me LNK1120. I have added the lib folder to my projects Additional Library Locations (or something like that) in the solution properties. I am new to the whole Linking language thing, coming mostly from a Python/Java background. Any suggestions? I have tried a brute google search and tried a lot of the suggestions I have seen.

Comment: In addition to "look in this directory for libraries" (or something like that), did you also elsewhere say "link with this specific library" or something like that? You have to do that, too.

Comment: @Pete Grr... No I didn't. I will google that and see if I can figure out where that option is.

Comment: It's hidden under Proj Props -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies. Whatsa' matta' witchoo? :-)

Comment: Unlike all the other property windows I have been in in VS2010, when you click "edit" on this one the window that pops up doesn't have a "add new" button, just a text box, so I can't just use a file explorer to select them. If they are in a "lib" subfolder in my project directory, is the syntax "lib\Magick++.lib" or what ever for them all or do I have to give the absolute file path.

Comment: Also, isn't the point of an expensive Robust IDE like VS Ultimate so you DON'T have to deal with things that are a pain in the... "neck" like this?!?!? </rage rant>

Comment: Heh! Yeah. But you happened to hit the worst, most-anti-intuitive case; everything else (almost) you have at least a hope of finding if you look long enough. Who ever heard of calling a "library files" choice by the name "additional dependencies"?

Comment: As to lib file paths, you already handled that, as you said in your original question. Right?

Comment: Still something it doesn't like. Same error.

Comment: LNK1120? I [em]think[/em] that's the fatal error msg that says goodbye. What's the error that led up to 1120?

Comment: Don't know now that it isn't giving that error any more, I didn't see this until you had worked me past that error. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put the foregoing comments interchange in the form of a real answer:

To convince VS20xx to **link your app with some non-standard library**, including maybe a new library that you just built:

Under the VS main-menu "Project" tab, take "<your-project-name> Properties ..." and then

First, tell the linker where to look for a lib (like make -L):

1. Linker --> General
2. In the "Additional Library Directories" edit box, give the paths -- just the directories -- where lib files live.

Second, tell the linker what library files you want to lilnk with (like make -l):

1. Linker --> Input and then
2. In the "Additional Dependencies" edit box, add the space-separated unadorned lib-file name(s), no quotes needed, like:

   Additional Dependencies      mysqlclient.lib libcurl.lib mynewlib.lib

That *should* be it. (yeah, suuuuuuuuure :-)

Comment: HEY! Something changed! It seems to make it farther now, now it says "LNK1101: cannot open file '.obj'"

Comment: Well, let's take a look at that litle ol' LNK1101 error. It seems like that might mean that the compiler put the .obj somewhere funny. So: where is that? And where is the linker looking for it?

Comment: I'm NOT PULLING YOUR CHAIN. LNK1101 means (and I quote): "incorrect MSPDB80.DLL version; recheck installation of this product. The version of MSPDB80.dll available on your system does not match the version required by this tool." mspdb80.dll might have to do with the Program DeBug tool. '80' in the name means you're in dll hell now: the '80' version is being snubbed by somebody, maybe the run-time sys. It might be your static lib that can't live without mspdb80.dll . You can google for mspdb80.dll and download it; or you can rebuild your lib to be dynamic. I would try the former path first.

Comment: Yeah, that's the first thing I'd try: google and download mspdb80.dll , put it into system32, and see what happens then. This usually works, and I just ignore that it's also the depth of ad-hoc suckosity.

Comment: ... Got to love VS... working with it for 4 days and nothing to show. Ok, I will download and try that.

Comment: You're worried about a little two-year learning curve? feh! Man up, guy! :-)

Comment: If this doesn't work, shoot me some email and we'll take it offline. pete at pwilson dot net

Comment: Cool, thanks for all your help! I have VS2010 SP1 installing now, hoping that will fix it, downloading .dll's is blocked by my firewall here. If that doesn't fix it I will get the file off another computer.

Comment: Good move. OK, it's 1457 eastern time here. I have to go get a load of junk from my old house and I should be back here by 1630.

Comment: Nope, no change. Yeah I will get that dll over the weekend and loaded on monday and hope that fixes it, if not I might be emailing you.

Comment: Anytime. It's no fun to struggle all on your own without asking.

Comment: I got it fixed finally, it was a bunch of settings in the linker options. I basically cloned all the settings that were in the projects provided with image magick, I guess it is pretty picky!